# ReverseMatch worked for jsonResponse but not for render

Tags: python, django, url

I have a new page with:

```
   def person(request, galid):
       bunch of stuff
       context = { blah blah }
   # return JsonResponse(context)
   return render(request, 'pops/person.html', context)
```

with urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.index, name='index'),
       path('<slug:galid>' , views.person, name="person")
   ]
```

while `jsonResponse` worked perfectly fine, returning the context object at the desired galid string(a hex string). when I used `render` it throws:

```
   NoReverseMatch at /pops/7B909B19F98049948523899280807F9F
   Reverse for 'person' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) 
   tried: ['pops\\/(?P<galid>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

If there really is no reverse match, how does jsonResponse work fine? What is happening/ going wrong here? Thanks!

The offending href call is:

```
    href="{% url 'pops:person' id %}"
```

where `id` is the hex string.

Comment: Well that is logical, since there is no reverse url in the JSON response. Pelase show the problematic `{% url ... %}` tags in the `person.html` template.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem I just edited the problem description.

Comment: Does your `context` contains an `id` key? Is it set to an integer? Or is it `None`/empty string?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes it is set to the hex string. I was looping through using {% for id, person in dict.items %} Where each case the id is a hex string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The context in person doesn't contain an id key. Got it, it worked!